# Generate directed network with two separate degrees

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, igraph

I would like to generate a directed network that satisfies the following:

1. There are 100 nodes.
2. 50% of the nodes have exactly 3 outward connections.
3. the other 50% has 10 outward connections.
4. there are no self loops and the same node cannot be connected to another node twice

Is it possible to generate such a network?

An example network would look like this:

```
from  to
   1  54
   1  93
   1  32
   2  24
   2  21
   2  93
   3  21
   3  13
   3  19
   4  95
   4  100
   4  23
   ...
   50 4
   50 49
   50 56
   50 53
   50 86
   50 82
   50 19
   50 100
   50 34
   50 43
   51 21
   51 13
   51 49
   51 48
   51 39
   51 75
   51 39
   51 10
   51 4
   51 6
   ...
   100 4
   100 2
   100 19
   100 13
   100 11
   100 18
   100 13
   100 15
   100 49
   100 12
```

Comment: What you're describing is impossible - those outgoing connections have to go somewhere, and what you've described means that none of the nodes can have any incoming edges. Can you clarify?

Comment: In my example the second row consists only of made up numbers. if 2 is connected to 98, 98 can also be connected to 2. does that clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. What do you mean by "outgoing" and "incoming" connections, then? If 2 is connected to 98, doesn't that count as an incoming connection for 98? If 98 is connected back to 2, isn't that an incoming connection for 2?

Comment: right, thanks for pointing this out. what I'm looking for is an outdegree of 3 and 10. does that make it clear? I've edited the question

Comment: This is definitely possible (I can explain how in an answer). Were there any other guarantees you wanted to have about the structure of the graph, or just what you've given above?

Comment: The only important thing is that all nodes 1 to 100 should all have the desired outdegrees. THanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this that should be very easy to implement. Split the graph into the nodes 1 - 50 and the nodes 51 - 100. Then, lay out these groups of nodes, independently, into two rings, and connect each node in the first group to the three nodes that immediately follow it and each node in the second group to the ten nodes that immediately follow it. That gives you the properties you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI, so now I realized that I have one small problem with this network: nodes with degree of 3 will be connected to other nodes with a degree of 3 and nodes with degree 10 will be connected to other nodes with degree 10. Is it possible to mix this up somehow? so that some nodes with degree 3 are connected to nodes with degree 10 and vice versa?

Comment: @user2733997 Yes, this is definitely possible. In fact, it's not too hard to start with the current graph and modify it to get that result. I'll leave it to you to figure out how, since it's a good exercise.

Comment: I guess I can start connecting the ones with degree 3 not to their nearest neighbors but to their farest neighbors? it would be really great if you could help with the idea, constructing the network is also a good excercise :)